# How can I get index from an element in a mulitidimensional list?

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array, indexing

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```py
board = [[0, 1, 2, 3] , [4, 5, 6, 7] , [8, 9, 10, 11] , [12, 13, 14, 15,]].index("8")
print(board)
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError '8' is not in the list
```

How can I get the index from this element?

Comment: What is your expected output? 8 or 2?

Comment: Welcome to SO and thank you for your post! Unfortunately, as @Austin said, your post lacks clearance. What problem are you solving? What behaviour do you expect? Feel free to edit your post to add this information. Besides, some tips on posting on SO: '>' is usually used to represent quotes; when you insert a code snippet, it would be easier to read if it took up more lines, but the reader did not have to scroll it in width. Python allows you to write lists (and all other collections I can think of) down on several lines. I hope you stick around to ask more interesting questions!

Comment: Here are some extra tips on formatting code: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate and return the index value:

```
next((i for i, x in enumerate(board) if n in x), 'not found')
```

---

```
board = [[ 0 , 1 , 2 , 3 ] , [ 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 ] , [ 8 , 9 , 10 , 11 ] , [ 12 , 13 , 14 , 15 , ]]

n = 8
print(next((i for i, x in enumerate(board) if n in x), 'not found'))
```

This prints:

```
2
```

In case you want all indices of the value, switch to a list comprehension:

```
[i for i, x in enumerate(board) if n in x]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a built in way to do it. I would do it using numpy:

```
import numpy as np
board = [[ 0 , 1 , 2 , 3 ] , [ 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 ] , [ 8 , 9 , 10 , 11 ] , [ 
12 , 13 , 14 , 15 , ]]
b=np.asarray(board)
print(np.argwhere(b==8))
```

result : `array([[2, 0]])`

Answer (score 0):

this assumes there is only one occurrence of an element.

```py
board = [[ 0 , 1 , 2 , 3 ] , [ 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 ] , [ 8 , 9 , 10 , 11 ] , [ 12 , 13 , 14 , 15 ]]

var = [ele for ele in board if 8 in ele][0]

# check if element is not present in the list
if len(var) == 0:
    print('-1')

else:
    print('index: (', board.index(var), var.index(8), ')')
```

output:

```
index: ( 2 0 )
```

Answer (score 0):

What `index` in python does is find the element match which in your case are all lists and you are trying to match a `int`

You can use `numpy` to get the location

```
import numpy as np
board = [[ 0 , 1 , 2 , 3 ] , [ 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 ] , [ 8 , 9 , 10 , 11 ] , [ 12 , 13 , 14 , 15 ]]
np.where(np.array(board) == 8)
```

```
(array([2]), array([0]))
```

which is basically `board[2][0]`